# How can I implement a LabelTransformer in another directory?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

If I have a projects structured as:

```
- project/
  - deployment.yaml
  - kustomization.yaml
- bases/
  - transformer.yaml
  - kustomization.yaml
```

`project/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
bases:
  - ../bases
patchesStrategicMerge:
 - deployment.yaml
```

`bases/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
transformers:
  - transformer.yaml
```

If I then do `kubectl kustomize`, then the transformer does not get applied.

However if I do this:

```
- project/
  - kustomization.yaml
  - transformer.yaml
  - deployment.yaml
```

`project/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
patchesStrategicMerge:
 - deployment.yaml
transformers:
 - transformer.yaml
```

Then the transformer works and applies as expected.

To be clear, there aren't any errors with the first way, it just doesn't apply the transformer whereas the second way does apply the transformer. Is there a way I can lay out the directory structure the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2408

This appears to be by design which honestly makes sense. Theres no way to apply this transformation outside the directory.